# Cannot create mockito mock with __exit__ method

Tags: python, unit-testing, mockito, attributeerror, contextmanager

I am not able to attach `__exit__` method to a mockito mock in a test so that the mock don't mind when it is used in `with` statement.

Here is an example of a test that keeps raising `AttributeError: __exit__`:

```python
# main.py
class FooManager(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        print "Connect"
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        print "Dissconnect"
    def foo(self):
        print "Foo"    

def function_to_be_tested(manager):
    # type: (FooManager) -> None
    with manager:
        manager.foo()
```

```python
# test.py
from mockito import mock, verify, when, any as ANY

def test():
    manager_mock = mock()

    # none of this has any effect:
    manager_mock.__exit__ = lambda a, b, c: None
    when(manager_mock).__exit__(ANY(), ANY(), ANY()).thenReturn(None)

    function_to_be_tested(manager_mock)
    verify(manager_mock, times=1).foo()
```

The only solution that solved my problem is this:

```python
class ContextManagerMock(mock):
    def __enter__(self):
        return None
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        return None

def test():
    manager_mock = ContextManagerMock()
    function_to_be_tested(manager_mock)
    verify(manager_mock, times=1).foo()
```

However, I would like to know, why there is an `AttributeError` when I tried to attach the `__exit__` method by the `when` function or with the lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

You're likely just missing that you need to mock `__enter__` as well.

```
In [24]: m = mock()

In [25]: when(m).__enter__(...)
Out[25]: <mockito.invocation.AnswerSelector at 0x13db478>

In [26]: when(m).__exit__(...)
Out[26]: <mockito.invocation.AnswerSelector at 0x501bd00>

In [27]: with m: ...

In [28]: verify(m).__enter__()

In [29]:
```

If I don't mock `__enter__` I get an `AttributeError: __enter__`.